# How to import uniswap contracts to Brownie projects

Tags: solidity, uniswap, brownie

I would like to work with uniswap contracts but the problem is that I'm using brownie so I can't just use their npm package like this:

```
npm i --save-dev @uniswap/v3-sdk
npm i --save-dev @uniswap/sdk-core
```

How can I import their contracts to brownie?

I tried to fork their repo and import it as mine but because of that every contract has a wrong path for their imports.

Thakns

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises because brownie takes npm releases directly from github and `Uniswap` does not have any releases there.

But, if you modify your `brownie-config.yaml` like this it will refer to the default release:

```
dependencies:
  - uniswap/v3-periphery@1.0.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@uniswap=uniswap/v3-periphery@1.0.0'
```